# jquery event delegate with on() to datatables table

Tags: datatables, jquery, event-delegation

I have jquery datatable with 4 pages. When I load the page the click event works fine. From the second page onwards click event doesn't work. I read the http://api.jquery.com/on/
link, but I am confused making it work.

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead><th></th><th></th></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

```
$('#datatable tbody tr').find('td:gt(0):lt(9)').on("click", "", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation.
});
```

The table loads as ajax client side, when I paginate the table is refreshed with new data. How to attach the click event to the next set of rows

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNvhH/14/)

Comment: `$('#datatable' tbody tr)` --- what's this? ps: you don't use delegation - your second parameter in the `on()` call is an empty string

Comment: @zerkms `$('#datatable' tbody tr)` enables click for the rows in the tbody. the second parameter is empty because I didn't know what to include in that.

Comment: no it doesn't do that. It's a string literal and 2 undefined tokens (separated by space). This code is syntactically incorrect

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, its a typo `$('#datatable tbody tr')` I changed the quote at the end of `tr`

Comment: @zerkms can you please help me with this, I updated the question and also given an example in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right syntax should be:

```
$('#datatable tbody tr').on("click", "td:gt(0):lt(2)", function(e) {});
```

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't work with jQuery 1.7 (only the first row functions) but does with jQuery 1.8 onwards. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vogomatix/bNvhH/52/)